# Partner Page Header and Details Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am new to using Crystal Report in VB.NET and still learning new things and features.

**My Question**:
Is it possible to partner `Page Header A` and `Details A` while`Page Header B` is with `Details B`?

What I want to happen is like this:

**Page Header A:**

```
First Name      Last Name          Middle Name      Suffix
```

**Details A:**

```
john             Cena                Cruz               Jr.
Paul             Walker              Smith              Sr.
```

**Page Header B:**

```
Contact         Address             ZipCode           Country
```

**Details B:**

```
123456           Fifth Ave.          1630            Japan
645235           New York            20065            US
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible instead you can use two sub reports, In on report you show first set and in another show second set